# import module from a different directory

Tags: python, import, package, directory-structure

I have a project within which we write scripts for standalone utilities, in whatever language possible.

These scripts are separated on a team basis; as I work for the feeds team we keep everything in the feeds folder.

Now we are trying to take our frequently used module to create a sort of library and for this we are trying to make it generic in nature.

So I created the structure as below and now I'm trying to import modules and classes from lib but I'm getting error. Below is my dir structure. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for you help in advance

```
-- /u/user/qa-fo/bin/
        |----- __init__.py
        |----- pythonlib
               |----- __init__.py
               |----- linux_util.py
        |----- feeds
               |----- __init__.py
               |----- test.py
```

linux_util.py -

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

def test():
    print "hello test from linux util"
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
from bin.pythonlib.linux_util import test
print execute("date")
```

Here is the output on run

```
python feeds/test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feeds/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bin.pythonlib.linux_util import test
ImportError: No module named bin.pythonlib.linux_util
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running this from inside the bin directory. So you'd need to either have "/u/user/qa-fo/bin/" specifically on your PYTHONPATH, or just import from pythonlib:

```
from pythonlib.linux_util import test
```